# Deprecated Functionality Error in SessionManager.php on line 186 after update to 2.4.6

Tags: magento2.4.6

After updating my Magento store to version 2.4.6, I'm encountering a deprecated functionality error when visiting the admin page. The front-end, however, works fine.

Deprecated Functionality: Creation of dynamic property Magento\Framework\Acl::$_roleRegistry is deprecated in vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php on line 186.

The code at line 186 in SessionManager.php is

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['destroyed'])
    && $_SESSION['destroyed'] < time() - $this->sessionConfig->getCookieLifetime()
) {
    $this->destroy(['clear_storage' => true]);
}

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Deprecated Functionality: Creation of dynamic property Magento\Framework\Acl::$_roleRegistry is deprecated in vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php on line 186

<pre>#1 session_start() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:186]
#2 Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->start() called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Session/Interceptor.php:32]
#3 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session\Interceptor->start() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:123]
#4 Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->__construct() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth/Session.php:104]
#5 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session->__construct() called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Session/Interceptor.php:14]
#6 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session\Interceptor->__construct() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121]
#7 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:108]
#8 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:150]
#9 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:79]
#10 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:150]
#11 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:79]
#12 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:150]
#13 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:125]
#14 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->parseArray() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:86]
#15 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#16 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:109]
#17 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->__construct() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:14]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->__construct() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121]
#19 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:108]
#20 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#21 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:115]
#22 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:264]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:30]
</pre>
```

Result of grep -rn "magento/zendframework1" .

```
./dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testSkeleton/composer.lock:1819:                "magento/zendframework1": "~1.14.0",
./dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testSkeleton/composer.lock:2280:                "magento/zendframework1": "~1.14.1",
./dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testSkeleton/composer.lock:9570:                "magento/zendframework1": "~1.14.1",
./dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testSkeleton/composer.lock:9702:            "name": "magento/zendframework1",
./dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testFromClone/composer.lock:2518:            "name": "magento/zendframework1",
./dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testFromClone/composer.json:23:        "magento/zendframework1": "*",
./dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testFromCreateProject/composer.lock:1819:                "magento/zendframework1": "~1.14.0",
./dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testFromCreateProject/composer.lock:2280:                "magento/zendframework1": "~1.14.1",
./dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testFromCreateProject/composer.lock:9570:                "magento/zendframework1": "~1.14.1",
./dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testFromCreateProject/composer.lock:9702:            "name": "magento/zendframework1",
./dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Setup/Model/_files/testSkeleton/composer.lock:3991:                "magento/zendframework1": "1.12.10",
./dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Setup/Model/_files/testSkeleton/composer.lock:4169:            "name": "magento/zendframework1",
./vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testSkeleton/composer.lock:1819:                "magento/zendframework1": "~1.14.0",
./vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testSkeleton/composer.lock:2280:                "magento/zendframework1": "~1.14.1",
./vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testSkeleton/composer.lock:9570:                "magento/zendframework1": "~1.14.1",
./vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testSkeleton/composer.lock:9702:            "name": "magento/zendframework1",
./vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testFromClone/composer.lock:2518:            "name": "magento/zendframework1",
./vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testFromClone/composer.json:23:        "magento/zendframework1": "*",
./vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testFromCreateProject/composer.lock:1819:                "magento/zendframework1": "~1.14.0",
./vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testFromCreateProject/composer.lock:2280:                "magento/zendframework1": "~1.14.1",
./vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testFromCreateProject/composer.lock:9570:                "magento/zendframework1": "~1.14.1",
./vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testFromCreateProject/composer.lock:9702:            "name": "magento/zendframework1",
./vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Setup/Model/_files/testSkeleton/composer.lock:3991:                "magento/zendframework1": "1.12.10",
./vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Setup/Model/_files/testSkeleton/composer.lock:4169:            "name": "magento/zendframework1",
./vendor/magento/magento2-base/CHANGELOG.md:3727:    * ZF1 library is represented by 'magento/zendframework1', which is based on original "1.12.9" version and includes fixes for compatibility with Magento 2 application
Binary file ./.git/index matches
./vendor2/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testSkeleton/composer.lock:1819:                "magento/zendframework1": "~1.14.0",
./vendor2/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testSkeleton/composer.lock:2280:                "magento/zendframework1": "~1.14.1",
./vendor2/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testSkeleton/composer.lock:9570:                "magento/zendframework1": "~1.14.1",
./vendor2/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testSkeleton/composer.lock:9702:            "name": "magento/zendframework1",
./vendor2/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testFromClone/composer.lock:2518:            "name": "magento/zendframework1",
./vendor2/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testFromClone/composer.json:23:        "magento/zendframework1": "*",
./vendor2/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testFromCreateProject/composer.lock:1819:                "magento/zendframework1": "~1.14.0",
./vendor2/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testFromCreateProject/composer.lock:2280:                "magento/zendframework1": "~1.14.1",
./vendor2/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testFromCreateProject/composer.lock:9570:                "magento/zendframework1": "~1.14.1",
./vendor2/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/testFromCreateProject/composer.lock:9702:            "name": "magento/zendframework1",
./vendor2/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Setup/Model/_files/testSkeleton/composer.lock:3991:                "magento/zendframework1": "1.12.10",
./vendor2/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Setup/Model/_files/testSkeleton/composer.lock:4169:            "name": "magento/zendframework1",
./vendor2/magento/magento2-base/CHANGELOG.md:3727:    * ZF1 library is represented by 'magento/zendframework1', which is based on original "1.12.9" version and includes fixes for compatibility with Magento 2 application
./CHANGELOG.md:3727:    * ZF1 library is represented by 'magento/zendframework1', which is based on original "1.12.9" version and includes fixes for compatibility with Magento 2 application
```

Magento 2.4.6 Php 8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't face this error but let me try to help you debugging.

The call `Magento\Framework\Acl::$_roleRegistry`  is come from `Zend_Acl::_getRoleRegistry()` method which is included in the `Zendframework1` package (vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Acl.php).

In Magento 2.4.6, the `Zendframework` package was replaced by the `Laminas` package.

The appropriate Acl class is `Laminas\Permissions\Acl\Acl` (magento/vendor/laminas/laminas-permissions-acl/src/Acl.php) where they remove the underscore character in `$roleRegistry` property in `getRoleRegistry()` method to following PSR-2 coding standard.

The root cause of your issue is your project using `magento/zendframework1` package instead of `laminas` packages as Magento core.

Try to remove the `vendor` directory and run `composer install` to reinstall composer packages, maybe `magento/zendframework1` packages can be removed.
Then run the setup:upgrade command and compile code, deploy static content, and check to know if the issue is solved or not.

If the answer is no, that means one of your `composer.json` in your project code requires `magento/zendframework1` package. Let's search in the whole project code with the search term `"magento/zendframework1"` to get the result:
Run the below command in the Magento root directory:

```
grep -rn "magento/zendframework1" .
```

And add the output to your original question, I'll let you know the next step.

Comment: I update Result of grep -rn "magento/zendframework1" .
Thanks so much for your help Tu Van!

Comment: @Yohan the output looks good, nothing is incorrect here. Have you done the solution of deleting the `vendor` directory and running the commands?

Comment: Yes. I have changed the vendor directory name to vendor2, and then composer install. Then run the setup:upgrade command and compile code, deploy static content. Get the same issue.

Comment: @Yohan please run this command: `grep -rn "_getRoleRegistry" .`. If you received any results, please add them to your question, otherwise, please let me know in this comment section.

Comment: I don't get any results with `grep -rn "_getRoleRegistry" .`

Comment: That's weird. So, I suspect this is a cache issue. Do you use Redis and (or) Varnish for caching on your site? Which environment (Dev/Test/Staging/Production) are you working on this issue? Please remove `var/cache/*` and `var/page_cache/*`   directories and in case your site uses Redis cache, flush the Redis cache. Then rerun all Magento commands I mentioned above and check the result.

Comment: I have 5 stores (all 2.4.6. live and staging) on my server. two of them have this issue. As you guide I remove `var/cache/*` and `var/page_cache/*`, I turn off Varnish on server, tried to change the mode from production to dev. (because the non-issue stores are dev mode) then one of the issued stores doesn't show this error message and admin works!  Only one store left has this error. I'm using 'app/bootstrap.php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT);' for temperolary solution for that store. I will investigate more. Thank you Tu Van for your help! Appreciate much!

Comment: @Yohan you're welcome!

Comment: @yohan all the instances listed from your grep are test, so I would assume that sites that work composer is run with --no-dev and those that don't work have all the dev stack

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem.
I created an issue on github for it.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37469

I have also solved it temporary by editing SessionManager.php

```
//                if (isset($_SESSION['destroyed'])
//                    && $_SESSION['destroyed'] < time() - $this->sessionConfig->getCookieLifetime()
//                ) {
//                    $this->destroy(['clear_storage' => true]);
//                }

                if (isset($_SESSION['destroyed'])
                    && $_SESSION['destroyed'] < time() - $this->sessionConfig->getCookieLifetime()
                ) {
                    $this->destroy(['clear_storage' => true]);
                } elseif (!isset($this->_roleRegistry)) {
                    $this->_roleRegistry = null;
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and created an issue!
After I apply your solution, I get other error and now front-end get issue
(detail is on github) Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

Removing modules that have `magento/zendframework1` as dependency and clearing redis cache should solve the issue in most cases.